# Display turning off instead of just locking

Tags: screen, lock-screen

Whenever my screen locks, my display is also turning off. How can I set an automatic screen lock, without turning the screen off?

Whenever I change the setting for "Blank Screen" in the "Power" settings, it also changes "Blank Screen Delay" in "Privacy -> Screen Lock" settings. It seems as if there is no option of locking the screen without turning it off.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.03 with Gnome 3.36.8 with an external monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to install gnome-tweaks using:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

install gnome-extensions using:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

and then to install the **unblank** gnome extension from here: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1414/unblank/

Comment: This is the correct solution!